# Convert content of array to short string

Tags: arrays

Not sure if there is any good solution to do this but trying to wrap my head around it anyway.

Lets say that I have an array with items, maybe around 1000 items, representing all objects a user can add to their "inventory". Next, the user can select as many items it wants from that array and add to their own inventory.

Next I would like the user to be able to copy the content of that inventory, into a short string of numbers/letters that the user could send to another user (in plain text) and that user would be able to get the exact same inventory by just typing in the same short string, like "aFdEdfSf998872" or something smilar. Kinda like a url-shortner I guess.

To clarify, the order of the array that the items are picked from is always the same. The order of copied inventory does not need to be in the original order

My first thought was of course to just copy the index of each object into plain text but that could potentially make the string very long if there is a lot of objects.

Any one has any good ideas or pointer how this could be achieved or am I trying something impossible?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Was more looking about a general suggestion, but either C# or C++ works of course